# Solving corruption in a .htaccess flle

Tags: htaccess, hacking

I received a call from Go Daddy indicating that my site had been hacked and the .htaccess file is now an issue.

The code in my .htaccess file is as follows

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (google|yahoo|msn|aol|bing) [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} (google|yahoo|msn|aol|bing)
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ /help-insideit.php?p=$1 [L]

AddType application/octet-stream .gdb .gpx
```

Could someone advise me as to what could be corrupted?

Comment: It's not so much "corrupt" as it is "hijacked". You've likely got a PHP file named `help-insideit.php` somewhere in your directories (maybe several), and this _.htaccess_ file is rewriting requests (visits) from Google, Yahoo, MSN, etc... to that file. They're likely trying to redirect traffic from your site to theirs. I'd suggest working with GoDaddy's hosting support department for help locating and removing those PHP file(s) and resetting the _.htaccess_ file to what you previously had (or just empty it if nothing was in there before).

Comment: You should also change your passwords for your account access, FTP, and SSH...  See the bottom of their help guide here:  [Lock down a compromised account](https://www.godaddy.com/help/lock-down-a-compromised-account-6966).

Comment: You need to address how they got in... otherwise it'll just happen again and again. Time to check all logs.

Comment: Curious that the only relevant results in Google for `help-insideit.php` relate to two hacked sites from two years ago - also on GoDaddy! (Although the actual filename may be insignificant here, hence only two results.)

Answer (score 1):

you need to do a few things to fix the issue.

1. Change your FTP password, you need a strong password.
2. Remove the three lines starting with 'RewriteCond' and 'RewriteRule' in your htaccess file.
3. Delete the file 'help-insideit.php' from your server.

As commented above contact GoDaddy's hosting support department if you need help with it.